# react-native link error 'Unknown dependency'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm, agora.io

I'm following the example to build a small video chat: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-react-native-video-calling-app-using-agora

I created a new project via: `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

I added the necessary dependencies:

```
npm install --save react-native-agora
npm install --save react-native-router-flux
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

The dependencies can be also seen in the package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-agora": "^2.9.1-alpha.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
...
```

When i start the app via `npx react-native run-ios` the app will start on my *Version 10.2.1 (SimulatorApp-880.5 CoreSimulator-587.35)*

I get the following error: `Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null. constructor NativeEventEmitter.js`

I tried rebuilding it with `npm install` and the build was successful.

My guess is that i missed linking react to react-native-agora. I tried to link it with `react-native link react-native-agora` but i get the following error message:

`error Unknown dependency. Make sure that the package you are trying to link is already installed in your "node_modules" and present in your "package.json" dependencies.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to remove node_module and reinstall them using
`rm -rf node_modules`;
`npm install`
npm have been buggy at time

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with npm, as [Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5973377/nishant-patel) commented try deleting the `node_modules` folder and try `npm install` or `yarn install`.